# CSS loading within in-page style tags, but not from external stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm using this slide-in effect from CSS-tricks. It partly uses the visible plugin, and the animation is done via CSS.

http://css-tricks.com/slide-in-as-you-scroll-down-boxes/

It works when the CSS is loading in-page within style tags, but when I load it from an external stylesheet it doesn't. I've checked that the stylesheet is loading and it is. I'm wanting to load it externally to keep my CSS in one file. I've tried getting this to work in both HTML and wordpress, but get the same result. I use HTML5 Reset files. Thanks, Tim.

I've tried using: `@import url("slidein.css");` within style tags but that didn't work.

In Wordpress I load the javascript within an external file, ie.

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/index.js"></script>
```

within HTML:

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

The CSS in Wordpress:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/slidein.css" />
```

and HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css "href="assets/css/slidein.css" />
```

The javascript within index.js:

```
$.fn.offScreen = function(distance){

        var $t              = $(this),
            $w              = $(window),
            viewTop         = $w.scrollTop(),
            viewBottom      = viewTop + $w.height(),
            _top            = $t.offset().top - distance,
            _bottom     = $t.offset().top + $t.height() + distance;

   return {
     top: _bottom <= viewTop,
     bottom: _top >= viewBottom
   }

};

var win = $(window);

var allMods = $(".module");

allMods.each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  if (!el.offScreen(150).bottom) {
    el.addClass("already-visible"); 
  } 
});

win.on("scroll resize",function(event) 
{

  allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (!el.offScreen(150).top && !el.offScreen(150).bottom) 
    {
      el.removeClass("already-visible off-screen-top off-screen-bottom"); 
      el.addClass("come-in"); 
    } 
    else
    {

        if(el.offScreen(150).top)
        {
            el.addClass("off-screen-top"); 
        }
        else
        {
            el.addClass("off-screen-bottom"); 
        }
    }
  });//allMods.each()

});//win.scroll()

win.trigger("scroll");
```

The CSS:

```
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  background: #eee;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.module {
  width: 48%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform-origin: center center;
}
.module:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.module.off-screen-top {
  transform: translateY(-150px);
}
.module.off-screen-bottom {
  transform: translateY(150px);
}

body {
  background: url(http://s.cdpn.io/3/blurry-blue.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 30px;
}

.come-in {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 0.8s ease-out;
}

.come-in:nth-child(odd) {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.already-visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: none;
}
@keyframes come-in {
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, you should use `wp_enqueue_style()` to enqueue your external stylesheets, making sure to hook to `wp_enqueue_scripts`. For example:

```
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: The WordPress tag is used so I assumed PHP?

Comment: How do you know user3852061 is a he? For HTML, perhaps the path is wrong?

Comment: I've just edited my solution to clarify the solution is for WordPress.

Comment: Will enqueue my stylesheets, thanks. The path in HTML is correct - I've triple checked. I've also tried including the code in my general style sheet (which loads fine for both HTML and wordpress) and it doesn't work either.

Comment: @henrywright : I also face this problem when i tried to embed [google map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel) in my webpage.